# How can I prove that $(F \cap G)^\perp = F^\perp + G^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I need to prove the following relation:

> $(F \cap G)^\perp = F^\perp + G^\perp$, being $F$ and $G$ vectorial subspaces in $\mathbb R^n$

I have that $$(F \cap G)^\perp = F^\perp \cup G^\perp = F^\perp + G^\perp - (F^\perp \cap G^\perp)=F^\perp + G^\perp - (F+G)^\perp.$$

Is this reasoning correct? It seems like I would have to prove that $(F+G)^\perp=0$, but I don´t know how to get to this result.

Comment: Why do you think $(F\cap G)^\perp=F^\perp\cup G^\perp$? If $F$ and $G$ are the $x$- and $y$-axis in $\mathbb R^3$ then LHS is all of $\mathbb R^3$ while RHS is the union of the $yz$- and $xz$-planes. Furthermore, what is $U-U'$ for subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ supposed to be? I can't follow your reasoning at all.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:set-theory]?